# How to open two gmail accounts in Firefox

Tags: firefox, gmail

I am able to open two Gmail accounts in Chrome and IE (both latest versions). But when I try to do the same (using `Add Account` that appears next to `Sign Out`), Firefox (v32) opens Gmail window with the first account itself. Can anyone suggest me a way to get around this problem (without using addons) please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not using addons! They are perfect for your work! I prefer you using addons and Also I didnt understand how u are logged into more than one account in just one window? HOW? It it impossible! You should logout from one and then login to another... really confusing .

Answer (score 0):

If the new window is with the first account itself, you can change the Gmail account and password. Then, don't select the option of  auto logging your Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

You can link accounts. In the Gmail settings, Accounts tab, you can "grant access" to other accounts. If you have account Maria, and you grant access to account Anna, then Anne can open the account Maria, but not the other way around, unless you grant that too.

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to sign with multiple accounts. The problem was solved by deleting earlier Firefox settings. The fresh settings solved the problems, on multiple systems.